# Poner parámetros desde la UI a un editor SQL, React, Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux

Buen día. La idea de esto es que el usuario pueda agregar parámetros al editor SQL desde dos inputs, uno el parámetro y el otro el valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si escribe en el editor SQL agregas automáticamente inputs que son los parámetros y el valor.

Desde el editor SQl a los inputs funciona bien porque le paso una expresión regular. El problema está desde los inputs al editor, creo que es mas problema de lógica, pero aun no he encontrado solución. El caso es que al agregar un parámetro desde el input, se agrega de más, aunque siempre antes de agregar lo limpio pero parece que no afecta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import SQLContainerInput from '../Components/SQLContainerInput';

........

function arrayParamsExec(stringSql) {
 const paramsQueryText = [...stringSql.matchAll(/{{(\w+)}}/ig)];
 const newArray = paramsQueryText.map(item => item[1]);
 return newArray;
}

const initalStateCurrentChartInfo = {
  SQLQuery: '',
  dataType: 'TABLE',
  columns: [],
};

const CustomSQLEditor = ({
 fromQuery, // del Redux
}) = {
 const [currentChartInfo, setCurrentChartInfo] = useState(
  initalStateCurrentChartInfo,
 );
 const [params, setParams] = useState([]);
 const [textSql, setTextSql] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
   ....
   let sqlDefaultString = '';
   sqlDefaultString = fromQuery.internal_name
    ? `SELECT * FROM \`${fromQuery.internal_name}__${fromQuery.items[0]}\` LIMIT 20`
    : '';
   setCurrentChartInfo({
    ...currentChartInfo,
    SQLQuery: `${sqlQuery}`,
   });
 },[fromQuery]);

 // ------------------params---------------------
 const addProperty = () => {
  setParams([
    ...params,
   { name: '', value: '' },
  ]);
 };

 const updateProperty = (event, index, key) => {
  const newProperties = [...params];
  newProperties[index][key] = event?.target?.value;

  // agregar parámetros al editor SQL
  let sqlParams = textSql;
  if (key === 'name') {
    params.forEach(p => {
      if (p.name && /^\w+$/i.test(p.name)) {
        sqlParams += `{{${p.name}}}`;
      }
    });

    setTextSql('');
    setTextSql(`${sqlParams}`);
  }

  setParams(newProperties);
 };

 const deleteProperty = index => {
  const newProperties = [...params];
  newProperties.splice(index, 1);
  const newTextSQL = replaceAll(textSql, `{{${params[index]?.name}}}`, '');
  setTextSql(newTextSQL);
  setParams(newProperties);
 };

 // ------------------end params---------------------

 const changeTextEditor = (valueEditor) => {
    const namesParams = arrayParamsExec(valueEditor);
    const newProperties = namesParams.map((pName) => {
      const valueNew = params.find(p => p.name === pName);
      return {name: pName, value: valueNew?.value || ''};
    });
    setParams(newProperties);
    setTextSql(valueEditor);
 }

 return (
  <>
   <SQLContainerInput
     button={{
      onClick: handleSubmit,
     }}
     input={{
      value: `${textSql}\n`,
      onChange: changeTextEditor,
     }}
   />
   <DymanicKeyValueInputInput
     properties={params}
     updateProperty={updateProperty}
     deleteProperty={deleteProperty}
     addProperty={addProperty}
   />
  </>
 );
}
```

Entonces una solución puse otro valor que es `textSql` que se encarga colocar el string ya concatenado, y el string que viene del redux que es este valor `fromQuery`. Se pone el string del redux en una variable `sqlParams`, al agregar concatena con los parámetros y de ahí si limpio el `textSql`.

```
 ......
 const updateProperty = (event, index, key) => {
  const newProperties = [...params];
  newProperties[index][key] = event?.target?.value;

  // agregar parámetros al editor SQL
  let sqlParams = currentChartInfo.SQLQuery;
  if (key === 'name') {
    params.forEach(p => {
      if (p.name && /^\w+$/i.test(p.name)) {
        sqlParams += `{{${p.name}}}`;
      }
    });

    setTextSql('');
    setTextSql(`${sqlParams}`);
  }

  setParams(newProperties);
 };
 ......
```

El problema de ahí es que si escribo directamente del editorSQL, se resetéa todo el string
osea todo lo que se ha escrito y claro ahi si funciona colocando los parámetros no se
repite. Pero ahí no encuentro que forma hacer eso. Perdoname la ignoracia si estoy haciendo algo mal.

Esto es un ejemplo cuando uno escribe un sql largo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al agregar un parámetro desde el input, se resetea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un video de la demostración del error:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQBPOPyeXlI

link del repositorio: https://gitlab.com/albert925/parametrosui-a-editor-sql

**Actulización de posible solución**

muchas gracias @g.4, si funciona esa parte pero cuando agrego un parámetro desde el editor SQL y modifico en los inputs o agrego, se rompe lo que tenia antes. https://youtu.be/-fqRiAwa1Hs. Ya actualicé los cambios en el repositorio

Comment: ¿Tienes un repositorio donde puedas compartir la app? Saludos

Comment: hola @g.4 no, pero voy a crear uno. Es de un proyecto grande, asi que sacaré lo mas importante

Comment: Claro, la pregunta es interesante;  puede que al ver toda la secuencia, al menos de este componente, podamos replicar la situación de nuestro lado y depurar.

Comment: @g.4 ahi puse un video, mientras subo el codigo a un repositorio

Comment: @g.4 listo ahi ya lo puse en un repositorio, es este: https://gitlab.com/albert925/parametrosui-a-editor-sql

Comment: He logrado emular el caso de mi lado, sin embargo hay un detalle muy importante que debes aclarar, en el código de tu pregunta dice que `fromQuery ` viene de `redux`, entonces el dueño del estado debería ser `redux` y las modificaciones a mismo deberían ser mediante métodos `dispatch`, ¿Te mencionaron esto en los requerimientos? Saludos

Comment: Tengo esa duda pues, para lograr lo que mencionas, de poder agregar atributos al Query en el editor, se deberá modificar la estructura del estado `fromQuery`, y si se modifica en el componente como tal, se estaría codificando un patrón inválido.

Comment: hola @g.4. el fromquery no importa. Lo importante es en ese componente porque solo hace cambio de estado, el fromquery  se cambia ya cuando envío esa información al endpoint y la respuesta se guarda en fromquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Posible solución

Debido a la modificación que implementaste:

> Entonces una solución puse otro valor que es textSql que se encarga colocar el string ya concatenado, y el string que viene del redux que es este valor fromQuery. Se pone el string del redux en una variable sqlParams, al agregar concatena con los parámetros y de ahí si limpio el textSql.

El dueño del estado, al hacer un `keyStroke` en el editor de texto es la variable `endSql`:

```
const endSql = replaceAll(textSql, '\n', '');
```

Entonces, para que puedan persistir los cambios en el editor de texto, para cada evento `updateProperty`, se debe operar sobre `endSql`:

```
const updateProperty = (event, index, key) => {
    //codigo...
    // clean the string so that then add parameters to sql
    //let sqlParams = `${currentChartInfo.SQLQuery}`;
    let sqlParams = `${endSql}`;
    //codigo...
}
```

---

#### Controlando datos usando estado en ReactJS

Por último, sugiero manejar la variable `endSql` con un estado:

```
  const [params, setParams] = useState([]);
  const [textSql, setTextSql] = useState('');
  //aqui
  const [endSql, setendSql] = useState('');
```

Luego, en vez de asignar datos a la variable `endSql` directamente en el scope del componente `CustomSQLEditor`:

```
//const endSql = replaceAll(textSql, '\n', '');
```

Se controla el estado de la variable `endSql` con `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const endSql = replaceAll(textSql, '\n', '');
    setendSql(endSql);
  },[textSql]);
```

Con esta modificacíon mínima a la solución que implementaste previamente, se debería ya mantener/persistir las modificaciones del usuario al `Query SQL` en el editor de texto, cuando este agrega mas parámetros usando los `inputs`.

---

#### Actualización: Evitar parametros repetidos

Cuando se agregan `n` parametros a la consulta SQL, por medio de los `inputs` estos se van concatenando en la cadena `endSql`.

Ahora bien, cada vez que se invoca a `updateProperty`, se pasa la consulta SQL que se encuentra en ese momento en el editor de texto, con la variable de estado `endSql`.

Suponiendo que el usuario agrego un solo parametro, primera asignación `endSql`:

> SELECT * FROM `Tabla__item` LIMIT 20{{a}}

Suponiendo que el usuario quiere cambiar el nombre del parametro, se invoca nuevamente a `updateProperty`, pero la cadena`endSql` ya ha sido modificada durante la primera asignación, entonces su valor es:

> SELECT * FROM `Tabla__item` LIMIT 20{{a}}

El usuario cambia el nombre de la variable `a` por `b`, pero en ningún momento el método `updateProperty`, eliminó `a` de la cadena `endSql`, entonces su valor es:

> SELECT * FROM `Tabla__item` LIMIT 20{{a}}{{b}}

Y lo que se esperaba era:

> SELECT * FROM `Tabla__item` LIMIT 20{{b}}

Por lo tanto, si se asignan más parametros, se vera siempre la cadena `endSql` con asignaciones previas.

Ejemplo, suponiendo la creación de dos parametros:

> SELECT * FROM `Tabla__item` LIMIT 20{{a}}{{a}}{{b}}

Se observa que `a` estará repetida en `endSql`.

---

#### Posible solución

En los comentarios del metodo `updateProperty` se tiene el siguiente **hint**:

> clean the string so that then add parameters to sql

Se crea un nuevo método `cleanSQLString` para limpiar el string `endSQL` cada vez que el método `updateProperty` sea invocado; este método separa la estructura del query SQL y sus parametros en un `array`:

```
  const cleanSQLString = (string) => {
    //corto la cadena en {{
    //reemplazo {{ por "" en cada item
    //devuelvo el array con los reemplazos
    return string.split("{{").map(item=>item.replace("}}",""));
  }
```

Donde el array contiene:

- posicion[0] estructura Query SQL sin parametros
- posicion[1] parametro asignado con input

Después, se invoca al metodo `cleanSQLString` dentro de `updateProperty` y se pregunta:

- Si al array que representa a query SQL `endSQL` ya se le habían asignado parametros, entonces se asigna la estructura del query sin parametros `posicion[0]` a la variable `sqlParams`
- De lo contrario es la primera asignación, se aisgna `endSql` a la variable `sqlParams`:

  ```
    let currentSQL = cleanSQLString(endSql);
    // clean the string so that then add parameters to sql
    let sqlParams;
    if(currentSQL.length > 1){
      sqlParams = `${currentSQL[0]}`;
    }else{
      sqlParams = `${endSql}`;
    }
  ```

---

Para hacer las pruebas, hay que agregar el siguiente código en el componente `CustomSQLEditor`, primero el método `cleanSQLString`:

```
const cleanSQLString = (string) => {
    return string.split("{{").map(item=>item.replace("}}",""));
  }
```

Luego, al principio del método `updateProperty`:

```
const updateProperty = (event, index, key) => {
   
    let currentSQL = cleanSQLString(endSql);
    // clean the string so that then add parameters to sql
    //let sqlParams = `${currentChartInfo.SQLQuery}`;
    //let sqlParams = `${endSql}`;  
    
    let sqlParams;
    if(currentSQL.length > 1){
      sqlParams = `${currentSQL[0]}`;
    }else{
      sqlParams = `${endSql}`;
    }
    //codigo...
}
```

---

#### Notas de campo

- El método `updateProperty` sabe cual `input` se esta manipulando, pues recibe `index` como argumento.
- Además, hay un estado `params` que se encarga de ir acumulando los parametros que el usuario va agregando por medio de los `input`.
- El resto de operaciones en `updateProperty` usan estas dos variables `index` y `params` por cada `input`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, apliqué eso pero al escribir me sale repetido y agregando parámetros y tiene que ser el mismo que estoy editando, como la imagen que puse al principio. Si quieres haz la prueba del repositorio que puse. subo los cambios que me dijiste.

Comment: Ok reviso el repo con los cambios

Comment: Se actualizó la respuesta, al pendiente.

Comment: muchas gracias, si funciona esa parte pero cuando agrego un parámetro desde el editor SQL y modifico en los inputs o agrego, se rompe lo que tenia antes. https://youtu.be/-fqRiAwa1Hs. Ya actualicé los cambios en el repositorio

Comment: La estructura de un `query SQL` es mas o menos así: SELECT `attributes` FROM `relation` WHERE `predicate`

Comment: Ahora, el componente permite agregar `parametros` de dos formas:  1) usando llaves `{{param}}` desde el editor, si se usa esta notación estos `params` se ven reflejados en los inputs. 2) usando el botón Add y sus inputs, al hacer esto los `params` se verán reflejados en el editor.

Comment: Creo que el problema esta al usar el editor, si el usuario agrega un param con la notación {{param}} desde el editor **en cualquier posición de la estructura SQL que mencione, ya sea en `attributes`, `relation` o `predicate`** el componente si creará sus correspondientes `input`, pero supongamos que el usuario agrego un `param` en la posición `attributes` desde el editor y luego, quiere modificarlo usando su correspondiente `input`, el param seguirá disponible y actualizado en el editor, pero se mueve a la posición de los `predicate`, no se mantiene en la posición `attributes`.

Comment: Entonces lo que tu necesitas es mantener el param en la posición de los `atributes` del query SQL mostrado en el editor, cuando el usuario decida modificarlo desde su correspondiente `input`. Pero este requerimiento es extraño, puesto que los `input` **no especifican que posiciones en la estructura query SQL representan**, todos los `params` se van a ir hasta el final de query, en la posición  `predicate`, asi es como esta diseñado en este momento el componente.

Comment: Si mis comentarios tienen sentido y mi análisis es correcto, te sugiero una edición/replanteo de la pregunta basándote en lo que acabo de describir en relación al funcionamiento actual del componente y lo que se esta buscando. Es decir elimina el uso de la variable `endSql` y menciona el objetivo final, mantener los `attributes` en su posición dentro de la estructura query SQL en el editor, cuando el usuario trate de actualizar sus `params` desde sus correspondientes `input`.

Comment: Quedo en espera de tus comentarios, pienso borrar mi respuesta pues no tiene sentido, el componente no repite `params` , y parece que el problema es tal cual lo describí en los comentarios anteriores. Definitivamente la solución parece ser más compleja. Saludos

Comment: Por último, revisé nuevamente el código inicial sin las modificaciones que tu propusiste (el uso de la variable `endSql`) y funciona bien, se agregan parámetros al query desde el input y no se repiten al agregar un nuevo input, ya sea usando el editor o los inputs. Si decides modificar la pregunta te sugiero dejar el código original, sin el uso de `endSql`.

Comment: oh vale muchas gracias por la sugerencia @g.4. En ese caso hago otra pregunta nueva, pero de esta si ya está resulta. SI como dijiste esto es otro problema diferente a esta. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Gracias a ti colega, al menos ya tenemos bien el planteamiento y sabemos exactamente como atacar el problema, saludos

Comment: listo acá esta la otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/486448/mantener-los-attributes-en-su-posición-en-el-editorsql-react-js @g.4