# Mantener los attributes en su posición en el editorSQL. React, JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

buen día, esta la continuación de esta pregunta [Poner parámetros desde la UI a un editor SQL, React, Js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/484874/poner-par%C3%A1metros-desde-la-ui-a-un-editor-sql-react-js/485496?noredirect=1#comment864878_485496). Que ya se solucionó. En esta es cuando agrego un parámetro desde el editor SQL y modifico en los inputs o agrego, se rompe lo que tenia antes.

Esto está cuando se agrega parametros desde los inputs:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se escribe en el editor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ya cuando uno quiere editar el nombre del parámetros o agregar uno nuevo se borra todo que estaba antes y queda solo los parámetros en el editor SQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- acá un video de como sale el error: https://youtu.be/-fqRiAwa1Hs.
- este es el link del repositorio por si quieren probarlo: https://gitlab.com/albert925/parametrosui-a-editor-sql.

***El objectivo final es que el usuario puede agregar, editar y eliminar parámetros desde el editorSQL o de los inputs que sale abajo del editor. SI se escribe en el editor sql esto `{{param}}`, sale reflejado ya en los inputs. Si se agrega un parámetro desde los inputs o s e edita debe verse reflejado el cambio en el editor SQL.***

Eso ya está pero aun se me borra lo que contenía el string en el editor SQL, pensaba como buscar la posición donde esta esos parámetros, cortarlos y volver a posicionar el parámetro. pero se me rompe igual, esto es lo que puse:

```
  let sqlParams;

  if(currentSQL.length > 1){
    sqlParams = `${currentSQL[0]}`;
  }else{
    sqlParams = `${endSql}`;
  }
  console.log(sqlParams)
  // get parameter positions by regular expression
  const searchParamRegedix = arrayParamsExec(endSql);
  console.log(searchParamRegedix, 'searchParamRegedix')
  if (searchParamRegedix.paramsQueryText.length > 0) {
    console.log(111)
    // get the position
    const searchPosition = searchParamRegedix.paramsQueryText[index]?.index;
    // remove the old word in braces
    const deleteOldParam = replaceAll(sqlParams, `${searchParamRegedix.list[index]}`, '');
    // the remaining string is removed from the obtained position
    const deleteFirtsLetter = deleteOldParam.substr(searchPosition + 2);
    // the string is removed from the beginning to the position obtained
    const deleteRemaining = deleteOldParam.substr(0, searchPosition + 2)
    // the string of the beginning and end is combined with its parameter
    const contantString = deleteRemaining + event?.target?.value + deleteFirtsLetter;
    // the entire string is overwritten in the state
    setTextSql(contantString);
  }
  else{      
    params.forEach(p => {
      if (p.name && /^\w+$/i.test(p.name)) {
        sqlParams += `{{${p.name}}}`;
      }
    });

    setTextSql('');
    setTextSql(`${sqlParams}`);
  }
```

claramente sin la opción agregar el parámetro desde el input lo que implementé en código anterior funciona perfectamente.

esté es el codigo:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import SQLContainerInput from '../Components/SQLContainerInput';

........

function arrayParamsExec(stringSql) {
 const paramsQueryText = [...stringSql.matchAll(/{{(\w+)}}/ig)];
 const newArray = paramsQueryText.map(item => item[1]);
 return newArray;
}

const initalStateCurrentChartInfo = {
  SQLQuery: '',
  dataType: 'TABLE',
  columns: [],
};

const CustomSQLEditor = ({
 fromQuery, // del Redux
}) = {
 const [currentChartInfo, setCurrentChartInfo] = useState(
  initalStateCurrentChartInfo,
 );
 const [params, setParams] = useState([]);
 const [textSql, setTextSql] = useState('');
 const [endSql, setendSql] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
   ....
   let sqlDefaultString = '';
   sqlDefaultString = fromQuery.internal_name
    ? `SELECT * FROM \`${fromQuery.internal_name}__${fromQuery.items[0]}\` LIMIT 20`
    : '';
   setCurrentChartInfo({
    ...currentChartInfo,
    SQLQuery: `${sqlQuery}`,
   });
 },[fromQuery]);

 useEffect(()=>{
   const endSql = replaceAll(textSql, '\n', '');
   setendSql('')
   setendSql(endSql);
 },[textSql]);

 const cleanSQLString = (string) => {
   return string.split("{{").map(item=>item.replace("}}",""));
 }

 // ------------------params---------------------
 const addProperty = () => {
  setParams([
    ...params,
   { name: '', value: '' },
  ]);
 };

 const updateProperty = (event, index, key) => {
  const newProperties = [...params];
  newProperties[index][key] = event?.target?.value;

  // agregar parámetros al editor SQL
  let currentSQL = cleanSQLString(endSql);
  // clean the string so that then add parameters to sql
  //let sqlParams = `${currentChartInfo.SQLQuery}`;
  if (key === 'name') {
    let sqlParams;
    if(currentSQL.length > 1){
      sqlParams = `${currentSQL[0]}`;
    }else{
      sqlParams = `${endSql}`;
    }
    params.forEach(p => {
      if (p.name && /^\w+$/i.test(p.name)) {
        sqlParams += `{{${p.name}}}`;
      }
    });

    setTextSql('');
    setTextSql(`${sqlParams}`);
  }

  setParams(newProperties);
 };

 const deleteProperty = index => {
  const newProperties = [...params];
  newProperties.splice(index, 1);
  const newTextSQL = replaceAll(textSql, `{{${params[index]?.name}}}`, '');
  setTextSql(newTextSQL);
  setParams(newProperties);
 };

 // ------------------end params---------------------

 const changeTextEditor = (valueEditor) => {
    const namesParams = arrayParamsExec(valueEditor);
    const newProperties = namesParams.map((pName) => {
      const valueNew = params.find(p => p.name === pName);
      return {name: pName, value: valueNew?.value || ''};
    });
    setParams(newProperties);
    setTextSql(valueEditor);
 }

 return (
  <>
   <SQLContainerInput
     button={{
      onClick: handleSubmit,
     }}
     input={{
      value: `${textSql}\n`,
      onChange: changeTextEditor,
     }}
   />
   <DymanicKeyValueInputInput
     properties={params}
     updateProperty={updateProperty}
     deleteProperty={deleteProperty}
     addProperty={addProperty}
   />
  </>
 );
}
```

Perdóname las molestias, ya de tanto debuguear e investigar no he podido dar la solución por mi cuenta.